# Declaration is not applied unless "!important" is used

Tags: css, iframe, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a document that is meant to display in an iframe.  It needs to be displayed in 2 different sized iframes on my site, and I want to adjust the content accordingly.

In the the framed document, I have a div that's 570px wide. If the iframe is under 400px wide, I want this div to be 285px wide.

So, the CSS in this document has a media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
.sub-form {
    width: 285px !important;
   }
}
```

But it only works if I include the "!important".  Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible reasons why you need to include !important are:

```
.sub-form {
  width: 570px;
}
```

appears later on in your CSS file, or the wider width appears earlier but has higher specificity, ie

```
.some-div .sub-form {
  width: 570px;
}
```

I'm sure there could be other reasons as well.

Comment: Yes, I was unaware that i needed to match the level of specificity in my media queries.  Thanks.